# What can I do to speed up this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exists

Here is some detail, I tried to make a SQLFiddle but I kept getting errors with my variables. This works in Sql Server 2008.  My question is, how can I make my query faster? I know I'm doing a number of things wrong here (repeated nester queries), I'm hoping to get someone to take a look and help me get this down from its 30 minute execution time! :-S

The basic idea behind the query is that in the game I want to find all players which haven't moved 5 units for a period of time, who have fired whilst stood still and did not fire for 60 minutes before they stopped moving.

The query works, but it's the `AND NOT EXISTS` clause which is slowing things down to a crawl, before I added that it took 16 seconds to run! 16 seconds is still a long time, so any other improvements would be appreciated, but for now with this being my own POC game (just throwing bits and pieces together), 16 seconds is acceptable...

```
DECLARE @n INT , @DistanceLimit INT
SELECT  @n = 2 , @DistanceLimit = 5;

WITH    partitioned
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        CASE WHEN Distance < @DistanceLimit THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS PartitionID
               FROM     EntityStateEvent
               WHERE    ExerciseID = '8B50D860-6C4E-11E1-8E70-0025648E65EC'
             ),
        sequenced
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PlayerID ORDER BY EventTime ) AS MasterSeqID ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PlayerID, PartitionID ORDER BY EventTime ) AS PartIDSeqID ,
                        *
               FROM     partitioned
             ),
        filter
          AS ( SELECT   MasterSeqID - PartIDSeqID AS GroupID ,
                        MIN(MasterSeqID) AS GroupFirstMastSeqID ,
                        MAX(MasterSeqID) AS GroupFinalMastSeqID ,
                        PlayerID
               FROM     sequenced
               WHERE    PartitionID = 1
               GROUP BY PlayerID ,
                        MasterSeqID - PartIDSeqID
               HAVING   COUNT(*) >= @n
             )
    SELECT
DISTINCT    ( sequenced.PlayerID ) ,
            MIN(sequenced.EventTime) AS StartTime ,
            MAX(sequenced.EventTime) AS EndTime ,
            DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(sequenced.EventTime),
                     MAX(sequenced.EventTime)) AS StaticTime ,
            Player.Designation AS 'Player'
    FROM    filter
            INNER JOIN sequenced ON sequenced.PlayerID = filter.PlayerID
                                    AND sequenced.MasterSeqID >= filter.GroupFirstMastSeqID
                                    AND sequenced.MasterSeqID <= filter.GroupFinalMastSeqID
            INNER JOIN Events ON Events.FiringPlayerID = sequenced.PlayerID 
            INNER JOIN Player ON Player.PlayerID = sequenced.PlayerID
                                 AND Player.Force = 'FR'
                                 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT    *
                                                  FROM      Events
                                                  WHERE     Events.FiringPlayerID = Player.PlayerID
                                                  GROUP BY  Events.FiringTime
                                                  HAVING    Events.FiringTime BETWEEN DATEADD(minute,
                                                              -60,
                                                              ( SELECT
                                                              MIN(s.EventTime)
                                                              FROM
                                                              sequenced s
                                                              WHERE
                                                              s.PlayerID = filter.PlayerID
                                                              AND s.MasterSeqID >= filter.GroupFirstMastSeqID
                                                              AND s.MasterSeqID <= filter.GroupFinalMastSeqID
                                                              ))
                                                              AND
                                                              ( SELECT
                                                              MIN(s.EventTime)
                                                              FROM
                                                              sequenced s
                                                              WHERE
                                                              s.PlayerID = filter.PlayerID
                                                              AND s.MasterSeqID >= filter.GroupFirstMastSeqID
                                                              AND s.MasterSeqID <= filter.GroupFinalMastSeqID
                                                              ) )
            INNER JOIN Player HitPlayer ON HitPlayer.PlayerID = Events.HitPlayerID
    WHERE   HitPlayer.[FORCE] = 'HO'
    GROUP BY GroupID ,
            sequenced.PlayerID ,
            Events.FiringPlayerID ,
            Events.FiringTime ,
            Player.Designation
    HAVING  DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(sequenced.EventTime),
                     MAX(sequenced.EventTime)) > 5
            AND Events.FiringTime BETWEEN MIN(sequenced.EventTime)
                                  AND     MAX(sequenced.EventTime)
    ORDER BY StartTime
```

Comment: You might get a better answer on dba.stackexchange.com for performance tuning questions

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - Thanks, I'll post there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is materialize the `sequenced` CTE, since it is used 4 times in the overall schema of things.

This would mean moving around some code and using #temp tables in place of the sequential CTEs. It would also work out an order of magnitude better since you can cluster #temp tables and create useful indexes for the JOINs.

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5575/0) that shows that CTEs can be evaluated **many times**, once for each reference.

Comment: What do you mean by materialize it?  Is there any chance you could give me a hand?  I'm not fully wrapped my head around the code yet and moving lots of things around would likely lead to more mistakes than I can handle atm!

Comment: Thanks for your advice, changing the nested CTEs into temp tables dropped execution time back down to a more manageable 30 seconds :)